# TypeError: raw_input() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given in list option of method in Python

Tags: python, list, oop, methods

I want to collect a list of 3 subjects and their marks using class method in python OOP. but I am getting error :
TypeError: raw_input() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
(Sorry, but I have checked the relevant posts but could not get an answer please help me out.)
My code is:

```
class Students():
    def readStudentDetails(self):
        self.__name=input("Enter name : ")
        self.__rollno=input("Enter Roll no. : ")
    
        #self.__subjects=input("Enter subject : ")
        
        self.__subjects=[]
        for i in range(0,3):
             self.__subjects[i]=input("Enter subjects : ", str(i))
        
        self.__marks=[]
        for j in range(0,3):
            self.__marks[j]=int(input("Enter marks : ", j))    
        
    def displayStudentDetails():
        print("Name :", self.__name)
        print("Roll No :", self.__rollno)
        print("Subjects :", self.__subjects)
        print("Marks :", self.__marks)


    def computeGrade():
        self.__total=0
        for i in range (0,3):
            self.__total+=self.__marks[i]
            
        self.__average=self.__total/3
        if self.__average <50:
            self.__grade="F"
        elif self.__average <60:
            self.__grade="D"
        elif self.__average <75:
            self.__grade="C"
        elif self.__average <85:
            self.__grade="B"
        else:
            self.__grade="A"

s1=Students()
s1.readStudentDetails()
s1.computeGrade()
s1.displayStudentDetails()
```

**Error is :**

[image]

TypeError: raw_input() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Weird error, but it looks like you mean `input("Enter subjects : " + str(i))`

Comment: @khelwood yes...string format